# What is a good deployment directory structure for java console apps

Tags: java, unix

I have a Java console application that I am ready to deploy onto a Unix server. I am writing a shell script to run the application.

I plan to put my shell scripts in one folder, my application jar and dependent jars (spring, etc.) into a different folder and properties files (those that need to be maintained 'live') in a separate folder again. I would then have my shell script iterate through the files in the 'jars' and 'properties' folders, appending them to the classpath, before finally calling java ...

Is this a 'good' deployment structure? Are there any guidelines for how to arrange files to maximise maintainability and stability? Are there obvious 'wrong' ways to do this that are best avoided?

I should add that, for a previous project, I put all shell scripts (those that start java processes and those that don't) into a scripts folder, my application jar into a folder with the library jars in a library subfolder and external resources into a config subfolder. I then wrote a script that explicitly loads all the files. It was long winded to write and needs to be maintained whenever I upgrade a library jar. This time around I'd like to do it better. Also, it feels unnecessary to separate my application JAR from the libraries.

Comment: Maven could create a Manifest file for your jar with references to your library jars, then java itself would find those files. Also depending on how you "look" for the properties files you could get away with a single classpath entry for those. The job of writing the shell script would then be much reduced.

Comment: Thanks. I'll investigate using the maven-jar-pluging to ease my workload. I'd forgotten that manifest files could do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, this is what we use;

```
/
    /class
        //package hierarchy here, raw .class files
    /lib
        //library jars here, apache commons, gson etc, all .jars
    /conf
        //.properties files go here, including ones for libraries
    /doc
        //program documentation files, typically .txt
        /javadocs
            //java doc html root
    /sh
        //shell scripts including execute.sh and compile.sh
```

We use `ant` for building, often have a `src` folder for the source tree if necessary. This way you just add `/class` and `/lib` to your classpath, and that never changes.

Comment: This is what I had in mind. I guess it's good to see that it is used elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Good structure for your case is so called uberJar or oneJar, that can be made with number of utils, just google it. Also I can recommend such a nice piece of code as http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php

Comment: I can see how that would make classpaths and deployment easier. My concern is that it hides the actual libraries used in the deployment. Whilst it's theoretically possible to determine which versions of which jars were packaged in the uberjar, I can see the average maintainer having cause for concern.

Comment: check JarClassloader, it allows nested jars.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, if it is just a small app, I would put it all under `/opt/<my_java_app>` and have a directory substructure there just like you did in dev.

If you want to be more compliant with the UNIX recommended practices, then put your executable (including your `jar`) in `/usr/local/bin/<my_java_app>`, config files in `/etc/<my_java_app>`, log files and other data files in `/var/<my_java_app>`.

Also, you may want to refer to [this document](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

Build a system-native package, and use system defaults. If using Debian, create a .deb direct from your build system (for instance, using [ant deb task](http://code.google.com/p/ant-deb-task/)). If using rpms, use the [rpm task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/rpm.html). That way you can easily deploy, undeploy and update the application just like any other one.

The system package should separate libraries (I use `/usr/share/java/AppName` for my jars) and configuration (to `/etc/AppName` or `/home/UserName/.AppName`); the launch-scripts I symlink to `/usr/bin`. Beyond that, there is no great complication getting things to work. I recommend finding well-known java-based packages in your distribution and copying their launch scripts (in particular, their VM-locating magic).